# Difference between [^\d].* and ^[^\d].* in java regex

Tags: java, regex

`^[^\d].*` is to return true if the string does not have a number at the beginning. `[^\d].*` seems to work the same as `^[^\d].` What is the different between them?
What string can match `^[^\d].*` but not with `[^\d].*`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It depends on whether you use `matches()` or `Matcher.find()`**

- `[^\d].*` matches **one** character that is not a digit, then anything till the end of the line: for instance, `abc`.
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string. Therefore, `^[^\d].*` matches, starting at the beginning of the line, **one** character that is not a digit, then anything till the end of the line. It would match the line `abc`, but it would not match `abc` on this line: `1 abc`
- In Java, using the `matches()` method, there will be no difference as `matches()` matches if the pattern matches the entire string (it does not search for potential substring matches). Using `matches()` is the same as a using a regex fully anchored with `^` and `$`
- If you use `Matcher.find()`, you will observe the difference above, as it searches for matches anywhere in the subject string.

**Reference**

- [Using Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)
- [Java string methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)
- [Java `Matcher` Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)